# Runnable jar (ExceptionInInitializerError)

Tags: java, jar

I've got a problem which I understand but I have no idea how to fix it.
I have a class in my project that contains static fields with images or sounds so that I can use them everywhere without recreating variables every time.
One of the fields for reference (they are all the same):

```
public static ImageIcon mainMenuBg = new ImageIcon(Resources.class.getResource("img/menubg.png"));
```

Now my problem is that it works fine in Eclipse when I run it, but when I export the project to a runnable JAR, nothing happens. I then went in the command window and ran it from there, and I have this `ExceptionInInitializerError` due to my images. Basically, none of the images are recognized at runtime, so if I remove every image call, it works.

Also, it is worth noting that when exporting, the list of `Main` classes doesn't really update. If I change the project's main's name, it isn't added to the list. Might it be a problem with my main class specifically? If so, how can I fix that? I tried to recreate it already but nothing changed.
Could someone enlighten me about this problem, please?

Here is the printstacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Client.<init>(Client.java:53)
    at Client$1.run(Client.java:37)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Ressources.<clinit>(Ressources.java:41)
    ... 16 more
```

Where the lines pointed are lines in which I'm trying to load an image from my resources class.

Also, all of my classes are in the same package, the default one.

Finally, here is the 'jar tvf ...' command's result:

```
     153 Tue Jan 13 21:43:36 CET 2015 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Tue Jan 13 21:43:36 CET 2015 org/
     0 Tue Jan 13 21:43:36 CET 2015 org/eclipse/
     0 Tue Jan 13 21:43:36 CET 2015 org/eclipse/jdt/
     0 Tue Jan 13 21:43:36 CET 2015 org/eclipse/jdt/internal/
     0 Tue Jan 13 21:43:36 CET 2015 org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/
   978 Tue Jan 13 21:43:36 CET 2015 org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/JIJC
    onstants.class
   714 Tue Jan 13 21:43:36 CET 2015 org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/JarR
srcLoader$ManifestInfo.class
  4735 Tue Jan 13 21:43:36 CET 2015 org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/JarR
srcLoader.class
  1505 Tue Jan 13 21:43:36 CET 2015 org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/Rsrc
URLConnection.class
  1841 Tue Jan 13 21:43:36 CET 2015 org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/Rsrc
URLStreamHandler.class
  1149 Tue Jan 13 21:43:36 CET 2015 org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/Rsrc
URLStreamHandlerFactory.class
  1495 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 ChatPrive$1.class
  1792 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 ChatPrive$2.class
  1596 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 ChatPrive$3.class
  1897 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 ChatPrive$4.class
  1553 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 ChatPrive$5.class
  7565 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 ChatPrive.class
  2680 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Tour.class
  9003 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Move.class
  2622 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 InfosPartie.class
  1448 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Message.class
  3262 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Roi.class
  1464 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Case.class
   987 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 JoueurIA.class
   750 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 MenuCopie$1.class
  1307 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 MenuCopie$2.class
  2992 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 MenuCopie.class
  7882 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 ReceptionClient.class
  1138 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Chat$1.class
   851 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Chat$2.class
  3835 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Chat.class
  2263 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Fou.class
   832 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 MenuPromotion$1.class
  2081 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 MenuPromotion$2.class
  1401 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 MenuPromotion$3.class
  1216 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 MenuPromotion$4.class
  1216 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 MenuPromotion$5.class
  1216 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 MenuPromotion$6.class
  4231 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 MenuPromotion.class
  1501 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Jeu$1.class
   825 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Jeu$2.class
 10677 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Jeu.class
  1457 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 ChatAll$1.class
  1570 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 ChatAll$2.class
  1344 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 ChatAll$3.class
  1914 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 ChatAll$4.class
  1527 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 ChatAll$5.class
  9326 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 ChatAll.class
  1135 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PanelInfo$1.class
  1337 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PanelInfo$10.class
  1164 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PanelInfo$11.class
   963 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PanelInfo$12.class
  1335 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PanelInfo$13.class
   963 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PanelInfo$14.class
   830 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PanelInfo$15.class
   829 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PanelInfo$16.class
  1435 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PanelInfo$2.class
   576 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PanelInfo$3.class
  1748 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PanelInfo$4.class
  1356 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PanelInfo$5.class
  1552 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PanelInfo$6.class
  1556 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PanelInfo$7.class
   945 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PanelInfo$8.class
  1437 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PanelInfo$9.class
 16765 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PanelInfo.class
  1176 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 MenuUtilisateurs$1.class
  1173 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 MenuUtilisateurs$2.class
  1753 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 MenuUtilisateurs$3.class
  2228 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 MenuUtilisateurs$4.class
  2071 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 MenuUtilisateurs.class
  3996 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Piece.class
  3830 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PartieSolo.class
  3300 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 ConnexionClient.class
  1160 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 EchecGUI$1.class
  8154 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 EchecGUI.class
  6844 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Joueur.class
   677 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Client$1.class
   834 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Client$2.class
  2718 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Client$3.class
  1041 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Client$4.class
  1008 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Client$5.class
   983 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Client$6.class
  1096 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Client$7.class
  4611 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Client.class
  2783 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Pion.class
   663 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 JoueurReel.class
  1620 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 MessagePrive.class
  6302 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PartieEnLigne.class
  1911 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Cheval.class
  6817 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Ressources.class
  1235 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 NotificationMessage$1.class
  1348 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 NotificationMessage.class
  3835 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 PartieAmi.class
  1355 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 EmissionClient.class
  2999 Tue Jan 13 21:43:06 CET 2015 Reine.class
     0 Tue Jan 13 20:55:48 CET 2015 img/
   945 Sun Jan 11 19:40:24 CET 2015 img/attaque.png
196863 Fri Jan 09 22:59:04 CET 2015 img/board.png
595046 Sun Jan 11 22:04:40 CET 2015 img/board1.png
631303 Sat Jan 10 00:14:04 CET 2015 img/board2.png
   440 Sun Jan 11 22:32:28 CET 2015 img/boutonchat.png
   413 Sun Jan 11 22:32:46 CET 2015 img/boutonchatsel.png
   735 Sun Jan 11 21:53:46 CET 2015 img/boutonrecommencer.png
   793 Sun Jan 11 21:54:52 CET 2015 img/boutonrecommencersel.png
   258 Wed Dec 24 17:28:54 CET 2014 img/caseCible.png
   224 Sat Jan 10 18:23:04 CET 2015 img/casePleinePoss.png
  1100 Sat Jan 10 18:14:06 CET 2015 img/caseSelectionnee.png
   224 Sat Jan 10 18:14:30 CET 2015 img/caseVidePoss.png
  5962 Wed Dec 24 17:28:54 CET 2014 img/chevalblanc.png
  1203 Mon Jan 12 21:37:44 CET 2015 img/chevalblancmort.png
  1106 Sun Jan 11 00:40:14 CET 2015 img/chevalblancpromo.png
  5720 Wed Dec 24 17:28:54 CET 2014 img/chevalnoir.png
  1214 Mon Jan 12 21:37:44 CET 2015 img/chevalnoirmort.png
  1119 Sun Jan 11 00:40:50 CET 2015 img/chevalnoirpromo.png
  8080 Mon Jan 12 20:44:20 CET 2015 img/echec.png
 29956 Mon Jan 12 00:08:06 CET 2015 img/ecranpause.png
  3736 Thu Jan 08 00:14:42 CET 2015 img/fondlabel.png
  5783 Sun Jan 11 19:04:14 CET 2015 img/fondlabelblanc.png
  6968 Sun Jan 11 19:04:18 CET 2015 img/fondlabelnoir.png
  5327 Sun Jan 11 22:22:52 CET 2015 img/footer.png
  4087 Wed Dec 24 17:28:54 CET 2014 img/foublanc.png
  1024 Mon Jan 12 21:37:46 CET 2015 img/foublancmort.png
   887 Sun Jan 11 00:43:04 CET 2015 img/foublancpromo.png
  3987 Wed Dec 24 17:28:54 CET 2014 img/founoir.png
  1010 Mon Jan 12 21:37:48 CET 2015 img/founoirmort.png
   864 Sun Jan 11 00:43:24 CET 2015 img/founoirpromo.png
 10904 Sun Jan 11 01:19:48 CET 2015 img/historique.png
260917 Tue Jan 13 20:55:48 CET 2015 img/menubg.png
127477 Tue Jan 13 19:30:36 CET 2015 img/panelinfobg.png
   270 Sun Jan 11 22:13:34 CET 2015 img/pause.png
   256 Sun Jan 11 22:13:48 CET 2015 img/pausesel.png
  3817 Mon Jan 12 01:41:14 CET 2015 img/pionblanc.png
   979 Mon Jan 12 21:37:50 CET 2015 img/pionblancmort.png
  3813 Thu Jan 08 00:39:10 CET 2015 img/pionnoir.png
   992 Mon Jan 12 21:37:42 CET 2015 img/pionnoirmort.png
   379 Sun Jan 11 23:00:42 CET 2015 img/play.png
   377 Sun Jan 11 23:00:28 CET 2015 img/playsel.png
 37986 Mon Jan 12 01:17:54 CET 2015 img/promobg.png
   449 Sun Jan 11 22:58:14 CET 2015 img/redo.png
   439 Sun Jan 11 22:58:32 CET 2015 img/redosel.png
  5292 Wed Dec 24 17:28:54 CET 2014 img/reineblanc.png
  1245 Mon Jan 12 21:37:54 CET 2015 img/reineblancmort.png
  1140 Sun Jan 11 00:41:18 CET 2015 img/reineblancpromo.png
  5185 Wed Dec 24 17:28:54 CET 2014 img/reinenoir.png
  1222 Mon Jan 12 22:24:28 CET 2015 img/reinenoirmort.png
  1115 Sun Jan 11 00:41:40 CET 2015 img/reinenoirpromo.png
  5809 Mon Jan 12 00:11:32 CET 2015 img/reprendreBtn.png
  4946 Mon Jan 12 00:12:56 CET 2015 img/reprendreBtnsel.png
  5889 Wed Dec 24 17:28:54 CET 2014 img/roiblanc.png
  5717 Wed Dec 24 17:28:54 CET 2014 img/roinoir.png
  2152 Sun Jan 11 00:57:20 CET 2015 img/roque.png
  2144 Sun Jan 11 19:26:50 CET 2015 img/roqueblanc.png
  2099 Sun Jan 11 19:26:16 CET 2015 img/roquenoir.png
   529 Mon Jan 12 21:58:58 CET 2015 img/sonoff.png
   503 Mon Jan 12 21:59:24 CET 2015 img/sonoffsel.png
   686 Mon Jan 12 21:59:36 CET 2015 img/sonon.png
   623 Mon Jan 12 21:59:52 CET 2015 img/sononsel.png
   395 Sun Jan 11 22:43:30 CET 2015 img/surrender.png
   357 Sun Jan 11 22:43:46 CET 2015 img/surrendersel.png
   849 Mon Jan 12 19:40:22 CET 2015 img/tooltip.png
  4564 Wed Dec 24 17:28:54 CET 2014 img/tourblanc.png
  1146 Mon Jan 12 21:38:00 CET 2015 img/tourblancmort.png
  1008 Sun Jan 11 00:42:16 CET 2015 img/tourblancpromo.png
  4528 Wed Dec 24 17:28:54 CET 2014 img/tournoir.png
  1135 Mon Jan 12 21:38:04 CET 2015 img/tournoirmort.png
   986 Sun Jan 11 00:42:42 CET 2015 img/tournoirpromo.png
   453 Sun Jan 11 22:57:06 CET 2015 img/undo.png
   441 Sun Jan 11 22:56:48 CET 2015 img/undosel.png
  1326 Mon Jan 12 01:13:52 CET 2015 img/valider.png
  1393 Mon Jan 12 01:19:40 CET 2015 img/validersel.png
     0 Tue Jan 13 18:50:36 CET 2015 snd/
2248748 Mon Jan 12 23:35:38 CET 2015 snd/ambiancefeu.wav
 77868 Mon Jan 12 23:32:06 CET 2015 snd/attaque.wav
 25988 Tue Jan 13 00:08:06 CET 2015 snd/boutonclic.wav
397356 Mon Jan 12 21:02:50 CET 2015 snd/echec.wav
 43342 Sun Jan 11 23:59:36 CET 2015 snd/hover.wav
319532 Wed Jan 07 00:43:04 CET 2015 snd/message.wav
108464 Mon Jan 12 23:45:02 CET 2015 snd/played.wav
606552 Tue Jan 13 18:50:36 CET 2015 snd/promotion.wav
112156 Sat Jan 10 19:06:50 CET 2015 snd/select.wav
```

Comment: You failed to give us the 3 most important information: the complete stack trace of the exception, the package of the Resources class, and the content of the jar file (obtained using `jar tvf thejar.jar`).

Comment: In my experience ExceptionInInitializerError message are rather uninformative (without indicating the cause exception stack trace). If that is the case, perhaps you want to change the code to perform the initialization outside static blocks to get a better idea what is going on

Comment: Can you tell us whether those images are included in the jar file and their relative path as @JBNizet requested?

Comment: Done. Every image and sound file seems to be in the jar.

Answer (score 1):

After digging in documentation around I think that is possible that the problem is that you are using a relative path instead of an absolute path as explained here:

[http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/java/system/java-resource-loading-explained-absolute-and-relative-names-difference-between-classloader-and-class-resource-loading]

So please try:

```
ImageIcon mainMenuBg = new ImageIcon(Resources.class.getResource("/img/menubg.png"));
```

Comment: Sadly, no result. If it's any help, I made my main class as a JFrame with the design mode. I then, very late in my project, decided to rename my main class with refactor/rename. I had a warning message telling me it might not work the same (although they warned me about scripts which I don't have). Unfortunately, I hadn't exported the project to a jar for a while so I'm not sure the problem started from there. Although I am sure that it worked before I refactored AND added all of my resources to a single class with static fields. Thanks for the help btw, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use somthing like this for your images.

```
ClassLoader cldr = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
URL picture = cldr.getResource("files/gcf.jpg");
ImageIcon mainMenuBg = new ImageIcon(picture);
```

And for the sounds.

```
ClassLoader cldr = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
URL musicurl = cldr.getResource("files/gcf.wav");
try{   
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(musicurl); 
  Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();  
 clip.open(audioInputStream); 
  clip.start();
} 
catch (Exception ex){  
 System.out.println("loading ??");
}
```

(import java.net.*; for the URL class) 
Put your /files folder into the /src folder and create your JAR.

Comment: I tried this solution but it doesn't change anything unfortunately.